# Calculating CDF with Scipy for an UNIFORM distribution

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I had this question recently:

**"Suppose `X` is a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed between `3` and `8`. Which one of the following functions can be used to find `P(X<=5.8)`?"**

And the answer given was:

```
st.uniform.cdf(5.8,loc=3,scale=5)
```

But will it not be:

```
st.uniform.cdf(5.8,loc=3,scale=8)
```

I always get confused about loc and scale with scipy because unless I recall wrong for normal distributions you'll have `loc = mu` and `scale = std`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [SciPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html):

> Using the parameters loc and scale, one obtains the uniform
> distribution on `[loc, loc + scale]`.

So `loc=3, scale=5` gives the uniform distribution on [3, 3+5] = [3, 8].

Generically `scale` can be thought of as measuring the "width" of the distribution. It's very well-defined what that is for a uniform distribution, and for the normal distribution it also makes sense to think of standard deviation as one measure of width.

Comment: Interesting. This was pretty clear and very well explained. Thank you!